# Tab Bar view Controller [Swift 3.0 - Xcode]

Tags: swift, xcode, view, tabbar

Ive set up 3 View Controllers. Two of which are connected by a Tab Bar Navigation, and the third is accessed by button and segue. But when I navigate to the third View Controller and then back to the Second View Controller, the navigation bar disappears, making my first view controller unable to be accessed.
Can any one help me?

Comment: If it is the navigation bar that you need it to be displayed then use `self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false` . If it is the tab bar then use `self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true`. You should use these codes either at `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear`.

Comment: Use an unwind segue to return to your second VC. Don't use a standard segue which creates a new VC.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this scheme [scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YW889.png)

I think your problem is that when you return from the third controller you create a new object, but must return to the old one